# How to upgrade my Cardano node to version 1.30.1 from a Coincashew install?

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-node, ubuntu, linux, spo

I installed and configured my node by following [the tutorial from Coincashew](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node).
Currently running with version 1.29.0, could someone give a procedure to upgrade my node to the higher version safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[1.30.1 release note:](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases/tag/1.30.1)** *All SPOs and node users **must update** to this (or a later) version prior to the HF to Alonzo PV 6, or risk not being able to sync to the network.*

**IMPORTANT: As usual, don’t forget to backup your nodes before starting these updates.**

**STEP 1 - Clone the latest source and checkout the branch 1.30.1**

```
cd $HOME/git
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node.git cardano-node2
cd cardano-node2/
git fetch --all --recurse-submodules --tags
git checkout tags/1.30.1
```

**STEP 2 - Make sure to have at least ghc 8.10.4 and cabal 3.4.0.0**

```
ghcup upgrade
ghcup install ghc 8.10.4
ghcup set ghc 8.10.4
ghc --version
ghcup install cabal 3.4.0.0
ghcup set cabal 3.4.0.0
cabal --version
cabal update
```

**STEP 3 - Configure & Compile**

```
cd $HOME/git/cardano-node2
cabal configure -O0 -w ghc-8.10.4
echo -e "package cardano-crypto-praos\n flags: -external-libsodium-vrf" > cabal.project.local
cabal build cardano-node cardano-cli
```

Now make sure that your version of your freshly built cardano-cli and cardano-node is correct (1.30.1):

```
$(find $HOME/git/cardano-node2/dist-newstyle/build -type f -name "cardano-cli") version
$(find $HOME/git/cardano-node2/dist-newstyle/build -type f -name "cardano-node") version
```

**STEP 4 - Shut your node down, replace your old binaries with the new ones in your bin folder and start your node again**

Stop the node

```
sudo systemctl stop cardano-node
```

Replace old binaries with the new ones

```
sudo cp $(find $HOME/git/cardano-node2/dist-newstyle/build -type f -name "cardano-cli") /usr/local/bin/cardano-cli
sudo cp $(find $HOME/git/cardano-node2/dist-newstyle/build -type f -name "cardano-node") /usr/local/bin/cardano-node
```

Double check the version

```
cardano-node version
cardano-cli version
```

Start your node again

```
sudo systemctl start cardano-node
```

Check the logs:

```
journalctl --unit=cardano-node --follow
```

Now clean your mess

```
cd $HOME/git/
mv cardano-node cardano-node-old
mv cardano-node2 cardano-node
```

Enjoy